# Is there a way to know how many times an SSD cell have been written?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, storage, smart, counter

When the system writes a SSD cell, does it increase a counter somewhere for each cell or in the MFT?

If yes, is there a way to know the counter of the cells, like a graph map of each cells ordered by number of writes?

Maybe we could know which cell are totally new (never been written) and which one have been written many times?

Answer (score 0):

The drive controller (built into the drive) would have access to and would use this information to do wear levelling. It would not be accessible at the disk partition level, but *might* be accessible to tools made by the drive manufacturer.

You, as a user, shouldn't need to care because the [wear levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) algorithm on the drive should make sure that blocks are evenly written rather than having some blocks never written and some that are at deaths door.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally retrieve the state of wear from an SSD by looking at its S.M.A.R.T values.  Different SSD's will use S.M.A.R.T values differently, but almost all will have an id "177" which is Wear_Leveling_Count" and which will give you some idea of the SSD's life.

You can access the S.M.A.R.T data from your drive using [smartmontools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/) or [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) or other tools.

Answer (score 0):

but i just wanted to know how health are the cells.

a visualisation like a hot map graph system will be very user full to prevent the failure.

imagine a software which can show me the SSD liek that : 
[ssd cells counter by cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ORQ8.jpg)
where red point are cell writtend X times and yellow dots are virgin cells.